# How to get a single property of a single item at an OGC API - Features endpoint

Tags: ogc-api-features

In my web browser, I can get a single item at an [OGC API - Features](https://ogcapi.ogc.org/features/) endpoint:

```
/wfs3/collections/{collectionId}/items/{itemId}.json
```

or a single property but for all items:

```
/wfs3/collections/{collectionId}/items.json?properties=prop1
```

but if I try getting a single property of a single item, the full item is return (i.e. all its properties):

```
/wfs3/collections/{collectionId}/items/{itemId}.json?properties=prop1
```

So, how could you get a single property of a single item?

Comment: The API document should contain documentation about all query types which are supported. Getting a single property may not be supported by that service.